# Internet Explorer 11 erroneously triggers "input" event immediately

Tags: javascript

I was debugging a strange JavaScript issue, and noticed what I think might be a browser bug in IE11. I'm posting here on StackOverflow as a sanity-check -- and maybe to make sure that someone else with IE11 can reproduce this.

The issue is that when a hidden input's value contains a HTML entity, an `input` event is triggered on the element immediately on page load.

Take a look at this isolated reproduction here: http://dobt-misc.s3.amazonaws.com/ie_11_bug.html

The source code of the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('input', function(){
        alert('Crap!');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  In IE11, refresh the page. You will see an alert, whereas in other browsers, you will not see an alert.

  <form>
    <input id="foo" type="hidden" name="utf8" value="&#x2713;" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me confirm whether or not this is a browser bug? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: There is an open bug regarding this problem: [Input elements with unicode entity character values cause "oninput" events to be fired on page load](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/816137/ie-10-11-input-elements-with-unicode-entity-character-values-cause-oninput-events-to-be-fired-on-page-load)

Comment: This problem persists in IE10+

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might encounter this, you can use this "class" as an alternative to the onInput event.

```
const getFieldWatcherInstance = (function(watchedElement, onElementValueChange){
        let intervalReference = null;
        let lastValue = null;
        if(!watchedElement instanceof Element) return new Error('watchedElement is not an HTML Element');
        if(typeof onElementValueChange !== 'function') return new Error('onElementValueChange is not a function');
        return {
            toggleFieldWatching : function(){
                if(intervalReference){
                    clearInterval(intervalReference);
                    intervalReference = null;
                }
                else{
                    intervalReference = setInterval(function(){
                        const currentValue = watchedElement.value;
                        if(lastValue !== currentValue){
                            onElementValueChange(currentValue);
                            lastValue = currentValue;
                        }    
                    }, 100);   
                }    
            }
        };    
    });
```

Set it up like this:

```
const myInputChangeWatcher = getFieldWatcherInstance(<**insert real element reference here**>, function(newValue){
console.log('The new value is: ' + newValue);
});
```

call myInputChangeWatcher.toggleFieldWatching() in the onfocus and onblur events of the input